# When using Publishing feature, how to link to a document in a document library?

Tags: document-library, document, publishing-site, publishing-page

When using a Publishing site, users can link to an image stored in the Images library (that library having been created as part of using the Publishing template.)

I like the fact that the link is a pointer to the image, not just a copy of it, so if the image itself is changed the image will be updated in all places that have linked to it.

In a similar way, I also want users to be able to insert links to documents that are stored in the Documents library (ideally via the rich text editor.)  I can't see how to do this though -- is it possible out-of-the-box?

Comment: Actually i have the same question. And the above link is no more valid. Can somebody post the answer? The first answer is a solution but not as comfortable as the one using for images. When you are editing a page you have these place holder, where you can click "click here to add image". Wehen you are clicking you directly get the brwoser diaglog for selecting that image. The same thing i would like to have for selecting a document...

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a little simplistic but I am not clear on exactly what you want to achieve.

If you want to link to a document held in a Document Library then simply click on the hyperlink button on the toolbar of the Rich Text Editor.  Select browse and then on the left hand side choose:

**Current Site:** Your Document Library

You can then select your document and this will create a link to that document in your page.

Let me know if this is not the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

see if the below link helps you out

http://vspug.com/mindykelly/2007/09/11/add-a-link-to-a-document-within-a-document-library-in-moss/